# Batch script to move XML files to the corresponding folder - folder name is written in the XML

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch scripting so any help is very appreciated.

I have to create a batch that moves XML files to corresponding folders - the folders name is written in the XML files.

The folders name is a number that is between tags:

```
<DeliveryLocationNumber>123456789</DeliveryLocationNumber>
```

and in this case the XML-would have to be moved to the folder C:\docs\123456789

Also there are many XML docs so I think that this should be done with some sort FOR function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The tags are missing from the original post <"DeliveryLocationNumber">

Comment: Please show more from your xml file. Batch depends on input pattern.

Comment: What have you tried yourself to achieve this? SO isn't ment to let people write code for you, but solve problems you are stuck with yourself. I encourage you to read the FAQ again.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%f IN (*.xml) DO (
 (SET destdir=)
 FOR /f "tokens=2delims=<>" %%i IN (
   'find "</DeliveryLocationNumber>" ^<%%f'
   ) DO SET destdir=%%i
 IF DEFINED destdir CALL :moveme %%f
)
GOTO :eof

:moveme
ECHO MD c:\docs\%destdir% 2>NUL
ECHO MOVE %1 c:\docs\%destdir%\
GOTO :eof
```

simply delete the ECHO keywords in the :moveme routine to actually create the destination directory and move the file. The ECHO ensures that the proposed actions are merely reported to the screen, not actioned.

What's happening is:

For each .XML file:

1. Force the value of `DESTDIR` to be deleted
2. Examine each line containing `</DeliveryLocationinNumber>`
3. Parse that line into tokens delimited by `>` or `<`
4. select the second token and assign it to `DESTDIR`
5. If `DESTDIR` was set (ie. a Delivery... line was found)
6. then CALL the routine `:moveme` passing the filename in %%f as parameter #1

The `:moveme` routine then can use the value of `DESTDIR` and `%1` (the first parameter delivered to `:moveme`) to build the appropriate MD (make directory) [the **2>NUL** suppresses any potential error message - like the directory already exists] and MOVE statements